# Autosuggest on input of specific character with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete, reactjs

So when using facebook if you enter an @symbol it knows you want to link to a friend/page.  Im putting together a UI that allows users to mark up text from ancient documents. What I would like to do is if a user highlights a word or puts an @ # ~ £ symbol before a word it pops up an autosuggest or options dropdown. So if I typed 'This is a document related to @name' when I typed @name it suggests names, or places etc, in fact I will need it to open another modal so you can enter more information about that user/place/item.

Im wondering if this is something that can be achieved with ReactJS from the documentation I cant seem to find this functionality out of the box, any pointers greatfully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is possible. 
I won't use the actual syntax, but I'll point you in the right direction.

Say you have your search/input component.

It's render function will look something like:

```
render: function(){
    return (<div>
            <input onChange={this.onChange}></input>
            <SuggestionsList data={this.state.value} show={this.state.autoSuggest}></SuggestionsList>
           <div>);
}
```

Now let's create the onChange function to set the state to show the autoSuggest when we want it to:

```
onChange: function(val){
    var state = {value: val};
    if(val[0] === '@'){
       state.autoSuggest=true;
    }
    this.setState(state);
}
```

All you need to do now is create the SuggestionsList component which will handle getting the suggestions and returning the list.

Note that you don't need to use this exact pattern, it may be more correct not to return the suggestionslist at all if you don't want to show any suggestions, but this is up to you.

I suggest you follow facebook's comments tutorial here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Where they dynamically get comments from the server and update. It's essentially the same pattern.

Comment: OK many thanks for the help, I need to get my head around this and have a play. Very rusty on Js and using React for the first time. This should be fun!

Comment: @PaulM Check out this open source react-autosuggest component: http://react-autosuggest.js.org/