# Material UI - Autocomplete that will show options ONLY when I type @ just like the way skype does or any other chat editor

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

Do we know any way to handle Material UI auto complete to display the autocomplete list only when a specific KEY (like an @) is typed ?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. But, there is no inbuilt prop inside Auto-complete API of Material-UI that does this. You can create a functional component that would accept the hide/show state of the component.

You can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188553/autosuggest-on-input-of-specific-character-with-reactjs) which uses the first character to check whether to suggest or not. You can also apply specific highlighting to it as well.

```
onChange = (event) => {
     if(event.target.value[0]==="@"){
         // some component with data to              
         // be shown
     }
}
```

Check out this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/jukben/pen/bYZqvR) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem, with auto-complete for domain names. Try this.

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
stringify: (option: any) => {
    let emailBeforeAtSign: string = "";
    if(clientDataFormState.email.includes("@")){
        emailBeforeAtSign = clientDataFormState.email.split('@')[0];
        return emailBeforeAtSign + "@" + option;
    }else return ""
}
```

});

Then, on your `<AutoComplete>` component you use `filterOptions`.

Something like this

```
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    filterOptions={filterOptions}
    disableClearable
    {... other options} 
/>
```

Let me know if worked!